# Read one line of csv with image link

Tags: php, image, csv

I've never worked with cvs before, so please bear with.

I've got it printing neatly with the following code. Now, what I want to do is, the 4 column of this file contains a number. I would like to be able to link either just that number or actually cells 2-4 to an image that corresponds to that number.

(i.e. 
XHS2 links to /images/2.jpg
PNM3 links to /images/3.jpg
...)

Can I do this?

Actual page: [I want to be able to link each line/the "code" section to a lightbox photo](http://needyounowequine.com/alumnicodes.php)

```
<?Php 
echo "<html><body><table border=1>";
$f = fopen("file.csv", "r");
$fr = fread($f, filesize("file.csv"));
fclose($f);
$lines = array();
$lines = explode("\r\n",$fr); // IMPORTANT the delimiter here just the "new line" \r\n, use what u need instead of... 

for($i=0;$i<count($lines);$i++)
{
    echo "<tr>";
    $cells = array(); 
    $cells = explode(",",$lines[$i]); // use the cell/row delimiter what u need!
    for($k=0;$k<count($cells);$k++)
    {
       echo "<td>".$cells[$k]."</td>";
    }
    // for k end
    echo "</tr>";
}
// for i end
echo "</table></body></html>";
?>
```

Comment: Look to use PHP's built-in fgetcsv() function rather than explode()

Comment: can you give as an axample of your csv file?, also you said you want to read one line, but in the code you read all file...

Answer (score 0):

With not being 100% of your CSV structure and what exactly you want to achieve, first off you can make your life easier using native PHP commands for parsing CSV files, such as [str_getcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) or [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php). After you get your array, parse the number from the fourth element (or is it from the second one? it's not clear in the question) and add it to your image url like:

`$url = 'image_path/' . $your_number . '.jpg';`